# Ion slide box - how to slide full width iframe videos in ion slide

Tags: javascript, iframe, ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

On my page I am having an ion-slide-box for images. Since in my app users will be able to embed videos, I should also add iframes with videos to the same slider. This is how my code looks like now:

This is my html:

```
<ion-slide-box ng-if="slider.length > 1">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in slider">
    <img ng-if="item.image" ng-src="{{ fileServer }}/imagecache/cover/{{ item.image }}" class="cover">
    <iframe ng-if="item.video" src="{{ item.video | safeUrl }}"></iframe>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

This works fine with only images, but when I have videos I can't slide them if they take up 100% width, which I have set up in my css, I can only slide them if they are wide less than that and if I slide them only on that part where the iframe is not taking up space in the slider. Since I need to have iframe taking up 100% width, I wonder how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ion-slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/) instead?

ion-slide-box is [deprecated](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

> ion-slide-box will be removed in the next Ionic release in favor of
>   the new ion-slides component. Don't depend on the internal behavior of
>   this widget.

Comment: I noticed that with both ion-slide-box and ion-slides I get the same result, seems like I can only slide iframes with videos around the bulletpoints. So I am wondering how to make that for the whole iframe.